# Change navigation bar color on android react native(Only on single page, not through out the app)

Tags: react-native

react-native-navigation-bar-color is not working for me.Any other solution to change nav bar color on androi in react native?

Comment: Hey, could you please provide more details on what you have tried so far? Code samples would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

go into this path `..android/app/src/main/res/values` find **styles.xml** 
and add this item :
 `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#212e34</item>`
this is my color code #212e34 change it what ever you want

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your android style, Go to **android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml file**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the StatusBar of react-native.

```js
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native'

...
...

  <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

Comment: Thanks but i need to change nav bar color, not status bar

Comment: Then I need further information. Which route are you using?

Comment: Using react navigation v3( stack navigator, drawer navigator)